# linq to sql c# same name for entity and aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm modifying an existing project to use linq to sql as a test.  I'm using linq to invoke stored procedures.

I was having a little trouble getting things to work.  It just wasn't working at all like the examples I've seen and the tiny experiments I had done beforehand - and then it struck me.  I think I know what the problem is, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

So here is the code:

```
        using (TEMPDataContext dbc = new TEMPDataContext(connectionString))
        {
            List<TEMPquest> qlist = new List<TEMPquest>();
            qlist = (List<TEMPquest>)dbc.GetTEMPQuestByID(id);
            if (qlist.Count == 0)
            {
                if (debug_level > 1) …
            }
            else if (qlist.Count > 1)
            {
                if (debug_level > 1) …
            }
            else
            {
                // There is exactly one row of data, so use it to populate the controls on the aspx side

                TEMPquest tq = (TEMPquest) qlist[0];
                int id = tq.uid //<=== NOPE!
            }
```

That comment line with the big "NOPE!" on it is causing the problem.  It turns out that the page that this code behind is supporting is called TEMPquest.aspx.  So when I declare the variables qlist and tq, it's using the page and not the entity!  All of the properties of those variables are properties of the page, not the entity!

I could fix this by changing either the page name or the table / entity name, but I would prefer not to be as unobtrusive to my boss's work as possible.  Is there a way I can programmatically refer to the OTHER TEMPquest - the entity - rather than the page?

I was thinking dbc.TEMPquest, but that's not it.  Is there a way to do this other than renaming either the page or the table / entity?  (Nothing tricky, please. If it's not simple, then I'll rename stuff.)

Comment: Why are you even bothering to ask? Renaming the page would likely take all of 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable with full Namespace.

```
var qlist = new List<My.Namespace.ToEntity.TEMPquest>();
qlist = (List<My.Namespace.ToEntity.TEMPquest>)dbc.GetTEMPQuestByID(id);
```

and

```
var tq = (My.Namespace.ToEntity.TEMPquest) qlist[0];
```

Comment: I'll try it momentarily

Comment: "My" is not recognized.  Tried it with just Namespace, as in new List<TWeb.ToEntity.TEMPquest>, but no luck.  It doesn't recognize ToEntity or ToEntity().

Comment: "My.Namespace.ToEntity." is just a placeholder for your Namespace. Replace all of it with your namespace